# I cant quite get cloth sawing down on my character

Tags: cloth-simulation

I am trying to add some clothes on my character.
I saw two main ways of doing this. First by selecting vertices and duplicating them and scaling them up. I tried it, but it didnt work quite well because my vertices look like this.
[image]

Also ignore the arms, I moved them 1 unit away so they don't affect the clothing wrapping up the body. I should have sculpted it in a T pose but I didn't know how to pose it after without messing up the vertices. I think there was something related to weight paint but i just want to 3d print this, so the ability to animate it doesen't matter to me.
Second way i tried, was by sawing.
It went ..
I am going to let this explain everything..]
[image]
[image]

I need help.
Thank you for reading and thanks in advance if you try to help me.

This is the blend file if you need it.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simulation looks good, it just needs a few tweaks.

1. Fix the arms first ;-) The sleeves can collide and get messed up there. Either rotate them in `Edit mode` or use the `Pose Brush` in `Sculpt mode` (increase the brush size)
2. In `Object mode` apply the `scale` to the shirt (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>)
3. In `Edit mode`, select the whole mesh the shirt (<kbd>A</kbd>), then `flip normals` (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>) because your shirt is turned inside out
4. In `Edit mode`, scale the shirt a bit up (~20%) because you need more fabric to wrap around the body
5. Move the shirt closer to the body by scaling it down along the X-axis (<kbd>S</kbd>, then <kbd>X</kbd>). Make sure the threads to not intersect with the body.
6. In the Cloth settings, reduce the `distance` for `Object Collision` and in `Self Collision` to `0.005 m`. If Self Collision is too low the mesh can 'explode', if Object Collision it's too high the fabric starts to 'crawl' and flips over the head.
7. Start the simulation. It should look good after 15-20 frames. If not, cancel it, and tweak the settings or try another start position for the shirt.
8. The seams might have some gaps. I could not find out why this is so. And there can be rough wrinkles. But you can fix this after you applied the cloth modifier.
9. If you're happy with the result `duplicate` the shirt (<kbd>D</kbd>) in `Object mode` to create a backup object.
10. `Apply` the `Cloth modifier` in the drop-down menu on the Modifier panel.
11. To remove the gaps switch to `Edit mode`, select everything, and do a Merge By Distance (<kbd>M</kbd>, `0.017 m`). You can adjust the distance in the dialog that appears (<kbd>F9</kbd> brings it back if you missed it). Have a look under the arms if they are all gone.
12. To smooth the rough wrinkles on the shoulder switch to `Sculpt mode`, use the `Smooth brush` with a strength of `0.2` and smooth it. The `Inflate brush` can be used to bring the volume back if you have smoothed too much. (The Cloth brush can be used to add more wrinkles. Use a Subdivision modifier is needed.)
13. Congratulations! You have made it! The simulation is a bit choppy. Small changes in the values can have big effects and it usually takes several attempts to get a good result.

[image: shirt front]

Back view:

[image: shirt back]

Comment: This is my new attempt. Its definetly an improvement. Also i don't understand how your "squares" look  so clean
https://imgur.com/a/yxDGf7Q
This is the blend file
[<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=vm6L23Nw" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/vm6L23Nw/)

Comment: It looks good although there is still this strange gap and the sleeves have a problem. The reason for the problem is that you have created a backup copy of the arms. They are invisible in the viewport but are still used to calculate the collisions by Blender. Move the arms copy to a new collection (key  M) and disable the collection. Then it's really hidden. Increase sewing force to 90 and the sleeve will look good. The gap can be filled quickly with the F-tools (key F). I'm going to update the answer later.

Comment: To have the "squares" (the faces) look smooth, just do a right-click in object mode on the object and select "Shade Smooth". That's it :-)

Comment: Thank you a lot for taking your time to help me.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/CU1RYGR   End result. Thanks again.